# Get Child Custom Post Content on Single.php?

Tags: wp-query, query, single, child-pages, get-children

I have a custom post type, with children 2 rows deep...

Outfit 1

> Inner
>
> > Child 1
> >     Child 1
> >     Child 1
> >     Child 1

Outfit 2

> Inner
>
> > Child 1
> >     Child 1
> >     Child 1
> >     Child 1

On the inner page, i need to show the content of the children, title, custom post types the normal stuff..

I have the following which does show the child content, but also that of the Outfit 1 and Inner..

```
      <ul>  
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'outfit','posts_per_page' => '-1','post_child' => 0 ) ); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <li>
         <?php the_title(); ?>
          <?php the_content(); ?>
        </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>

  </ul>
```

Any idea how to limit it to just the children below Inner?

This is code that obviously appears on single-outfit.php also...

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you try to just get the children and ignore the parent. 
Dont know where

```
post_child => 0
```

comes from but I'd use

```
post_parent => $parent_id
```

instead. In that case you have to catch the parent ID before you do any new queries.
If you do something like this at the beginning of your template:

```
$this_page_id = $post->ID;
```

you can refer later, in your new Query, to that id and just query child pages by using

```
post_parent => $this_page_id
```